# Passing a value from the Store to AJAX query string in React/Redux app

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga, superagent

If i make a request given below, everything works fine:

```
var ofst = 0;

function* GettingJson(offset=ofst){
var url = `/api/publishbooks/skip=${offset}&limit=12&sort=publishDate&sortDir=desc&_=1501513343421`;
const res = yield request.get(url);
}
```

But, of course, i want **ofst** to bring it's value from the store and i have a container component with *mapStateToProps* function which returns parameter - **offset: state.OffsetReducer**:

```
class BookListContainer extends Component{

componentWillMount(){
    this.props.ajaxRequestTriggeredMethod();
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <BooksList DataInputParam={this.props.books} BtnClickHandler={this.props.buttonClickedMethod} />            
        </div>
    );
}
}


const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return{
        books: state.BooksReducer,
        offset: state.OffsetReducer
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        buttonClickedMethod: () => dispatch({type: 'BUTTON_CLICKED'}),
        ajaxRequestTriggeredMethod: () => dispatch({type: 'AJAX_REQUEST_TRIGGERED'})
    };
};


const BookListContainerExported = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(BookListContainer);
```

So, i i'd like to assign **this.props.offset** to **ofst**:

```
var ofst = {this.props.offset};
```

But that doesn't work, probably, because at the moment, my **GettingJson()** generator is defined outside the container component.

**Question №1:** Is it necessary to define ajax request generator only inside a container component in order to have access to **this.props.offset**? Maybe, there are some other ways?

**Question №2:** If i define **GettingJson()** inside container component (as one of it's methods), how am i supposed to call it?
At the moment it is called from redux-saga and it works fine:

```
const ApiCallSaga = function*(){

while(yield take('AJAX_REQUEST_TRIGGERED')) 

    try {
        yield put({type:'AJAX_REQUEST_STARTED'});
        const result = yield call(GettingJson);
        yield put({type: 'AJAX_REQUEST_OK'});
    }catch (error){
        yield put({type: 'AJAX_REQUEST_ERROR'});
    }

};
```

but when GettingJson() is defined as container's method, then invocation which is given above, doesn't work properly and i'm getting **AJAX_REQUEST_ERROR**.

Answer (score 0):

Saga generators shouldn't be defined in container/regular components at all.

If you want to get a value from store in a saga use the `select` effect.

```
const offset = yield select((state) => state.offset);
const result = yield call(GettingJson);
```

If you want to get a value from props that isn't in the store, send it in the action payload.